# Secondary Picker's 'ForEach' gives me Fatal Error: Index Out of Range

Tags: foreach, swiftui, picker

I get this error every time I launch a ***secondary*** picker. 
The first picker works okay.

However when *I switch pickers* & scroll, I get the following:

[image]

Here is my entire code (written as a test of this problem):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem = 0
    @State private var isMainPickerHidden = false
    @State private var isSecondaryPickerHidden = true

    var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tartan"]
    var sizes = ["Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Super Size"]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedItem, label: Text("Please choose a color")) {
                        ForEach(colors.indices, id: \.self) {
                            Text(self.colors[$0])
                        }
                    }.hiddenConditionally(isHidden: isMainPickerHidden)

                    Text("You selected: \(colors[selectedItem])")
                        .hiddenConditionally(isHidden: isMainPickerHidden)
                }

                VStack {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedItem, label: Text("Please choose a size")) {
                        ForEach(sizes.indices, id: \.self) {
                            Text(self.sizes[$0])
                        }
                    }.hiddenConditionally(isHidden: isSecondaryPickerHidden)

                    Text("You selected: \(sizes[selectedItem])")
                        .hiddenConditionally(isHidden: isSecondaryPickerHidden)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        isSecondaryPickerHidden = !isSecondaryPickerHidden
                        isMainPickerHidden = !isMainPickerHidden
                    }) {
                        Text("Switch Pickers")
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// =========================================================================================================

extension View {
    func hiddenConditionally(isHidden: Bool) -> some View {
        isHidden ? AnyView(hidden()) : AnyView(self)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

What is the correct syntax for the ForEach{} to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use the same `selectedItem` for both pickers.

If in the second picker you select the last item (index 4) and then you switch to the first picker (max index = 3), then in this line:

```
Text("You selected: \(colors[selectedItem])")
```

you'll try accessing the index which is *out of range*.

---

To fix this you can use a separate `@State` variable for each picker:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedColorIndex = 0
    @State private var selectedSizeIndex = 0
```

```
Picker(selection: $selectedColorIndex, label: Text("Please choose a color")) {
```

```
Picker(selection: $selectedSizeIndex, label: Text("Please choose a size")) {
```